# Loading frames to 3D CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, tflearn

I have an 3D Convolutional Neural Network in Python with TFLearn.

Example code bellow:

```
def model_3d(self):
    """
    This function will build our 3D Convolutional Neural Network
    """

    #Layers
    net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 40, 80, 80, 3], name='InputLayer')
    net = tflearn.layers.conv.conv_3d(net, 32,  filter_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', name='Conv3D1')
    net = tflearn.max_pool_3d(net, kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2), name='MaxPool3D1')
    net = tflearn.layers.conv.conv_3d(net, 32,   filter_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', name='Conv3D2')
    net = tflearn.max_pool_3d(net, kernel_size=(2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), name='MaxPool3D2')
    net = tflearn.layers.conv.conv_3d(net, 64,   filter_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', name='Conv3D3')
    net = tflearn.max_pool_3d(net, kernel_size=(2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), name='MaxPool3D3')
    net = tflearn.layers.conv.conv_3d(net, 128,   filter_size=(2, 2, 2), activation='relu', name='Conv3D5')
    net = tflearn.max_pool_3d(net, kernel_size=(2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), name='MaxPool3D4')
    #FC Layers
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1024, activation='relu', name='FC1')
    net = tflearn.dropout(net, 0.5)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, self.n_classes, activation='softmax', name='FC3')
    net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', learning_rate=1e-5)

    return [net]
```

I'll use this model to learn and classify video. For this i wrote an algorithm that extract 40 frames per video and generates a folder with subfolders representing each class, a new dataset, basically.

My point is. Which is the best way to load these frames to this model?
Should i use mini-batch method with 40 examples (frames) or in case of 3D CNN, the input layer takes 40 images at a time from the dataset and learn from it?

I need to know how this model can learn from a set of 40 frames, once each class subfolder have 40 images per video, so, to detail, if i have 50 videos in a class, i have 50*40 frames in that folder.

I've searched a lot to solve this specific problem but nothing until now.

Thanks for the support and attention!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to create a numpy array of size m x n where m is the number of images you have for all classes and n is the number of pixel data points you have for each image. You will want to shuffle the classes beforehand so that there are not a bunch of the same class in a row. You don't want any one class over-represented in a given batch of your training data as that can throw off the weights of your CNN during training. From there you can feed mini-batches of the array you created to your CNN, making sure to reshape each row to your desired 2-D dimensions before training.